# ionic v1 TypeError: _.set is not a function

Tags: ionic-framework

I get the following error in my project:

```
TypeError: _.set is not a function
```

It doesn't matter if I type *ionic info* or *ionic cordova build android*

ionic cli always asks

*The Ionic CLI (local version) has an update available (3.7.0 => 3.9.2)! Would you like to install it? Yes / No*

Even if I type *No* I always get this error message.

Answer (score 0):

Try these steps

npm uninstall --save-dev --save-exact @ionic/cli-plugin-cordova

npm uninstall --save-dev --save-exact @ionic/cli-plugin-ionic1

npm uninstall --save-dev --save-exact @ionic/cli-plugin-gulp

Answer (score -1):

outdated version of the inquirer npm module

npm install inquirer

(Should update it from version 3.0 to 5.0 or so)